# What's the best way to versioning Android Gradle projects with flavors?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I work in a company with about 20 projects, all using various internal and external libraries. Currently we are migrating our Android projects to Android Studio and Gradle build. To make the migration with the minor impact to the app developers team, we create an migration checklist. One of most important itens in our migration checklist is the way of versioning of the different flavors in the version control (actually SVN).

Current (Eclipse ADT)

Two of our projects works with "visual skins strategy, containing one base-library-project, with all java codes, and various client-projects, normally using the base-library-project and only changing the image, drawable and text resources in 'res' folder.

The future (Android Studio + Gradle)

To migrate to Android Studio and Gradle build environment exploring to most of your  advantages, we consider the best way utilize the gradle flavors. So, the project structure after migration would as below (consider only the client-project because the base-library-project is in the artifactory):

```
  |- my-project
  |
  |- client-project
  |    |
  |    |- src
  |    |    |
  |    |    |- project-1
  |    |    |    |
  |    |    |    |-res
  |    |    |    | AndroidManifest.xml
  |    |    |    |
  |    |    |- project-2
  |    |    |    |
  |    |    |    |-res
  |    |    |    | AndroidManifest.xml
  |    |    |    |
  |    |    |- project-3
  |    |    |    |
  |    |    |    |-res
  |    |    |    | AndroidManifest.xml
  |    |    |    |
  |    |    
  |    | build.gradle
  |
  | /gradle
  | build.gradle
  | settings.gradle
```

But the SVN structure is:

```
 |- base-library-project
 |           |- trunk
 |           |- tags
 |           |- branches
 |
 |- client-project-1
 |           |- trunk
 |           |- tags
 |           |- branches
 |
 |- client-project-2
 |           |- trunk
 |           |- tags
 |           |- branches
 |
 |- client-project-3
 |           |- trunk
 |           |- tags
 |           |- branches
```

Our question is:
What is the best way to versioning of the flavors folders?
All in one SVN project? Separately? If separately, how?

Currently, in Eclipse ADT, each 'flavor' (or client) is one project and is versioned separately in SVN. But, sometimes, we need generate a version of one of the client-projects, and generate only your tag.

How you working with this scenario?
Have tips?

Thank you for share your experiences.

Answer (score 0):

Moving everything into one repository or keeping them separate comes down to personal choice. I have done something similar recently with a 'visual skin strategy' application like the one you mention above. For me I found it tidier to move everything in one repository.

If you wanted to keep separate repositories you would have to have a repository for project1, project2  containing resources,  Manifest etc and clone them into your client project src folder then add them as flavours in you client project gradle build file. Im not sure what you mean by 'generate only your tag' but if you want to build them separately you can using

```
gradleAssemble{Appname}Release
```

Another handy feature is that you can specify different package names in your flavour decleration.

```
 productFlavors {
    project1 {
        applicationId "com.client-project.parjectOne."


    }
```

This may alleviate the need for multiple manifest files.